# How does a prophage leave the host cell's genome?

Tags: rna, virus

I understand that, unlike a prophage, a provirus never leaves the genome, but I don't understand how the prophage "leaves".

Comment: The prophage is usually activated by cellular stress (bad nutrient conditions, toxic environment and so on) or cell damage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained reasonably well at [the Wikipedia entry for phage λ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_phage#Induction), which is the prototype lysogenic phage. Basically, integration occurs by site-specific recombination between the *attP* region on the phage genome and the *attB* region in the host genome. This means that in the prophage form the phage DNA is flanked by direct repeats. Excision involves the reverse process - recombination between these direct repeats. Excision is promoted by the phage-encoded Xis and Int proteins in combination with the host protein Ihf. The regulatory cascade which links cellular stress to this recombination event is detailed at the linked page.